# How to remove QTreeView indentation

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview, qtwidgets

I want to have a `QTreeView` **without** an indentation on the left side increasing at each nesting level. I tried setting `QTreeView::setIndentation(0)`. It removes the indentations just as I want, however it also hides the tree arrows.

---

#### Default behavior:

- With indentations ✗
- With arrows ✔

[image: Default behavior]

---

#### After `setIndentation(0)`:

- Without indentations ✔
- Without arrows ✗

[image: After setIndentation(0)]

---

#### Desired behavior:

- Without indentations ✔
- With arrows ✔

[image: Desired behavior]

---

So how can I achieve the result shown in the third example? Is there any standard way of doing it, or I will have to reimplement the `QTreeView::paintEvent()`, `QTreeView::drawBranches()`, etc.?

Comment: You need to reimplement it...

Comment: Just personal opinion but... I think what you're trying to achieve could be very confusing for users.  In the image labeled `Desired behavior:` how do I know if `1` is a subdirectory of `Test` or a subdirectory of `C:`?

Comment: @G.M. I agree, in this particular example it would very confusing for users. However, the actual tree structure will have more plain and static nesting. For example, imagine the grouping in property browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem I used a delegate to translate the paint of the items, and paint the arrows.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class BranchDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        QStyleOptionViewItem opt(option);
        if(index.column() == 0)
            opt.rect.adjust(opt.rect.height(), 0, 0, 0);
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
        if(index.column() == 0){
            QStyleOptionViewItem branch;
            branch.rect = QRect(0, opt.rect.y(), opt.rect.height(), opt.rect.height());
            branch.state = option.state;
            const QWidget *widget = option.widget;
            QStyle *style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();
            style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorBranch, &branch, painter, widget);
        }
    }
};

class TreeView: public QTreeView
{
public:
    TreeView(QWidget *parent=nullptr):QTreeView(parent)
    {
        BranchDelegate *delegate = new BranchDelegate(this);
        setItemDelegate(delegate);
        setIndentation(0);
    }
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override{
        QModelIndex index = indexAt(event->pos());
        bool last_state = isExpanded(index);
        QTreeView::mousePressEvent(event);
        if(index.isValid() && last_state == isExpanded(index))
            setExpanded(index, !last_state);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TreeView w;
    QFileSystemModel model;
    model.setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    w.setModel(&model);
    w.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir::homePath()));
    /*for (int i = 1; i< model.columnCount() ; ++i) {
        w.hideColumn(i);
    }*/
    w.expandAll();
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ellyanesc's answer works, but is incorrect by one small detail in the line:

```cpp
branch.rect = QRect(0, opt.rect.y(), opt.rect.height(), opt.rect.height());
```

The reason is because when the view is horizontally scrolled, `option.rect.x()` becomes negative. If `branch.rect.x()` is 0 (as in ellyanesc's answer), the branch indicator will always be shown, which also causes artifacts during scroll:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/O518A.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYJMj.png

To solve this, replace the above line with:

```cpp
branch.rect = QRect(option.rect.x(), opt.rect.y(), opt.rect.height(), opt.rect.height());
```

(I would have just pointed that out as a comment in ellyanesc's answer, but I don't have enough reputation for that.)

Answer (score 0):

eyllanesc's falls appart if there is horizontal scrolling. Also usually the view only expands/collapses when clicking the branch-indicator, not the index.

My Solution: Only change the Rect of indices which have a parent but no children. Also dont set the indentation to 0. No need to subclass QTreeView.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
class BranchDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    mIndent = 50;
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem opt(option);
        if(index.parent().isValid && (!index.model() || !index.model()->index(0, 0, index).isValid())) 
        { 
            opt.rect.adjust(-mIndent, 0, 0, 0); 
        }
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTreeView apView;
    BranchDelegate* const apDelegate = new BranchDelegate(apView);
    apDelegate->mIndent = 50;
    apView->setIndentation(apDelegate->mIndent);
    apView->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, apDelegate);


    QFileSystemModel model;
    model.setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    apView.setModel(&model);
    apView.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir::homePath()));
    /*for (int i = 1; i< model.columnCount() ; ++i) {
        apView.hideColumn(i);
    }*/
    apView.expandAll();
    apView.resize(640, 480);
    apView.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same question and I think there's an easier solution that hasn't been mentioned yet, which is to add a button that mimics the tree expansion icon by toggling expansion on click.

Here's how I did it:

```
            frame = ClickableFrame() # an implementation of QFrame that allows clicking
            toggle_tree = QPushButton()
            spacer = QSpacerItem(5, 1, QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
            label = QLabel(column)

            frame.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
            frame.setStyleSheet("background-color:  transparent;")

            frame.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.setExpanded(not self.isExpanded())
            )
            toggle_tree.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.setExpanded(not self.isExpanded())
            )

            frame.layout().addWidget(toggle_tree)
            frame.layout().addItem(spacer)
            frame.layout().addWidget(label)
            frame.layout().addItem(QSpacerItem(
                5, 1, QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed
            ))
            self.treeWidget().setItemWidget(
                self, 0, frame
            )
```